# How get id attribute of a TR when we know some value of TD with PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, html-table

Ex:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="WhatIneeDtoKnowValue">
<td>Something I know</td>
<td>Something I know again</td>
<td>Something I know too</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So I need to get the ID of the TR where I know the values of TDs !  I hope you understand me :)
I already used DomXpath to do the inverse thing (find the TD when I know the ID value of the TR) but in this way I can't find how.

Ps: I dont want use REGEX because here I simplify a lot the table but in my usage it's more complex !

Thank in advance if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPath expression like `//tr[td = 'Something I know' and td = 'Something I know again' and td = 'Something I know too']/@id` if you want to check all three conditions at the same time or simply e.g. `//tr[td = 'Something I know']/@id` if you want to check a single condition. You can also use positional predicates on the `td` checks if you want to check a certain `td`, e.g. `//tr[td[2] = 'Something I know again']/@id`.